# What is a good place to set the default value for a variable?

Tags: c#, oop

Is the class constructor the best place to set the default value for a variable?

In most of the code that I have inherited that seems to be the case.

**Example**

```
public class foo
{
    public bool IsAcidic { get; set; }

    public foo()
    {
        IsAcidic = false;
    }
}
```

Is this how you would do it?

Comment: @Adam,
How did you format the code? Did you actually enter these many spaces or is there something about tabs, that I don't know?

Comment: Have a look: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to assign some default values to any instance of that particular object then YES, constructor is the most appropriate place to assign them default values, but if you want to assign the default value of type to the field, then you don't have to do anything. Fields will be initialized with the default value of the type before the constructor. For example, if you have an `int` type field it will be assigned `0` by default and you don't have to do anything in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a variable to a value (explicitly or implicitly) as close to the creation of that variable as possible.

This is where C99 (as one example) started to shine. Up until that point, you had to create variables at the start of the function even though you may not know at that point what they should be. By having this disconnect, it was harder to keep track of what variables were set to what values. When C99 introduced the capacity to create new variables mid-function, this disconnect went away.

So, for your example, it's best to set default values in the constructor since that is where the variables come into existence.

If you *don't* do it in the constructor (for example, it's done in an `init` method call), then that's not the default value, simply because there is a time when those variables are set to something else.